# 2 AMD 7950's do not work in crossfire mode

Tags: drivers, ati, video

I have 2 7950 graphics cards.  I have tried to get them working in crossfire mode in several different ways all ending the same.  The computer boots to the login screen and then just freezes.

In order to break my computer out of this I have to open my case and disconnect the crossfire cable and boot and then reconnect it to try another method.

I tried the ubuntu additional drivers section and tried both version of the proprietary.

I even downloaded the drivers directly from the AMD website and it will not work.

Anyone have any insight on how to get this thing working?

I am only using 1 display and running Ubuntu 13.04.

EDIT : Small update it appears if I let it sit there long enough the system unfreezes, but if I move the mouse a bit it freezes again.  I didn't really see what happen after this.

Comment: Which drivers are you using?  I have had better results with the 12.x driver than I had with the 13.1 driver.  Also why do you need crossfire mode?

Comment: This is my driver amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13-4-x86.x86_64

I need crossfire because I have 2 7950s in my computer and I'd like to play some games in super high resolution with nice frame rates.  Also why not?

Do you have 7950s Ed?  What is your setup?

Comment: It is like the last little thing that doesn't work right on my new system.

Comment: I run dual 7950s without the crossfire bridge and they perform great. But I use the older driver (12.1) and I have the SDK installed.

Comment: I can run them without the crossfire bridge and that would be fine if I ran 2 displays, but I only have 1.

Try throwing on the crossfire bridge.  Does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was researching on how to install ATI driver for my laptop, I came across [this](http://forumubuntusoftware.info/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=9148s) webpage. In the **Post Install** section the author describes this command: `aticonfig --adapter=all --initial -f`, in a Note. If you have not tried this before, see if it works.

[This](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=163542) Arch Linux discussion pretty much gives all the commands and issues related to cross fire. I have used all the commands and all work except that CF cannot be enabled on my laptop. I thought it might be useful for you. Summing it up:

Add Multiple GPU chain:
`aticonfig --cfa --adapter=0,1`

Switch CF on:
`aticonfig --cf on --adapter=0,1` or `aticonfig --adapter=0,1 --crossfire=on`. Reboot to take effect.

Check if CF is enabled: `aticonfig --lscs`

See the load on the GPUs: `watch -n10 aticonfig --adapter=all --odgt --odgc`

See GPU chain info for each GPU: `aticonfig --lsch`

By the way, I am running Ubuntu 13.04 64bit with catallyst driver 13.4 for linux from AMD's website.

Comment: Doesn't work appears to freeze at the login screen just as before, but when running "aticonfig --adapter=0,1 --crossfire=on" it says unsupported platform.  Is it because it is Ubuntu 13.04?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I have no further input on this. I too got the same message but I thought it was because I was trying it on my laptop. Why don't you remove CF ribbon, boot and set the system up with the above commands, shutdown, boot the system after connecting the CF ribbon back..... Or may be you should wait for Catalyst 13.10 driver. If possible, put a bug report.....

Comment: Is it a known bug?  I reported it to AMD already, but I wasn't sure if it was already an open bug some where, or just an Ubuntu issue.